# Powershell script to checking services on multiple remote machines and to start them if they are not running

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell, My goal is to go through a list of remote Computers and check to see if certain services are running on them and starting the services if they are not. what would be the best approach in creating a variable for the services on said servers?

```
Server1.txt - 'ServiceA ServiceB ServiceC'
Server2.txt - 'ServiceD ServiceE ServiceF'
Server3.txt - 'ServiceG ServiceH'

$services = get-content .\Server1.txt

       

$services | ForEach {
    try {
        Write-Host "Attempting to start '$($.DisplayName)'"
        Start-Service -Name $.Name -ErrorAction STOP
        Write-Host "SUCCESS: '$($.DisplayName)' has been started"
    } catch {
        Write-output "FAILED to start $($.DisplayName)"
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

In your input, you have mentioned one text file for each server which is not advisable. Also there is no computer name in your Start-service Command. Please find my input sample below.

```
server1-serviceA,ServiceB,ServiceC
server2-serviceD,ServiceE,ServiceF
server3-serviceG,ServiceH,ServiceI
```

And here is the powershell script, since you have mentioned different services for each server there is a need for using split function.

```
$textFile = Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt

foreach ($line in $textFile) {

    $computerName = $line.split("-")[0]  #Getting computername by using Split
    $serviceNames = $line.split("-")[1]  #Getting Service names by using split

    foreach ($serviceName in $serviceNames.split(",")) {
        # Again using split to handle multiple service names

        try {
            Write-Host " Trying to start $serviceName in $computerName"
            Get-Service -ComputerName $computerName -Name $serviceName | Start-Service -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "SUCCESS: $serviceName has been started"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Failed to start $serviceName in $computerName"
        }
     
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the script for starting the service, but the loop works properly for multiple servers and their respective services. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the advice in using the split function, I was also wondering if there is a way to to pause between $computerName, the idea is to confirm that all $serviceNames in the are confirmed running before proceeding to the next set of $computername-$serviceNames

Comment: As a first step, try adding Start-Service -Passthru and verify the output. There are other ways also like using waitforstatus() and Do..until. please check stackoverflow for similar question. Hope the script I posted works for you.